# WPF C# Not Closing Window Correctly - Retains old SQL Data

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a WPF application that has multiple windows that it can open. When I run the program (debug from VS 2013), it opens `MainWindow.xaml`. When I tell `MainWindow` to open a secondary `Window` (let's call it `Win2.xaml`), it opens just fine. I can enter criteria, search the SQL DB for data, and complete my basic INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE work.

For purposes of this conversation, let's say I worked on `Customer1`. `Customer1` is now complete, so I save the data and close the window `Win2.xaml` (using `Close()`). Some time has passed and the database has a routine that changes a data element (marking an item complete, which should not allow `Win2.xaml` to find the record for `Customer1` on a search. i.e. `WHERE SENT = 0` and now the routine has changed `Customer1` to `SENT = 1`). Now I decide to open `Win2.xaml` again (**Note: I have NOT closed `MainWindow.xaml` yet, it is still running**) because I want to do some more work. **IF** I search for `Customer1`, based on the Stored Procedure and logic in the application, I should NOT find the record; however, the retrieve button pulls in the last known data for the customer. If I run the Stored Proc behind the Retrieve button, it returns 0 records for that customer, which is what I expect.

It appears that the `Win2.xaml` is holding onto resources even after `Close()`. If I simply restart the debug (or stop debugging and start it again), the `Win2.xaml` returns the "No Customers Found" message like it should.

So, what can I do here? Is this just a debug issue in VS? How can I completely DESTROY all records known to every aspect of the window and treat each new open as a truly new window?

Here is some code:

How the Window is opened from MainWindow.xaml

```
private void ListViewItem_DoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = (DependencyObject) e.OriginalSource;

    while (obj != null && !Equals(obj, PharmacyLv))
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof (ListViewItem))
        {
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
            var Item = (ListViewItem) sender;
            var pf = (Forms) Item.Content;

            var msgTitle = "Form Request " + pf.FormNamePharm;
            var msgCaption = "You requested to open " + pf.FormCodePharm + " - " + pf.FormNamePharm +
                             ". \nPress OK to continue or CANCEL to select again.";
            var result = MessageBox.Show(msgCaption, msgTitle, MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,
                MessageBoxImage.Question);

            switch (result)
            {
                case MessageBoxResult.OK:
                    switch (pf.FormCodePharm)
                    {
                        case "Win2":
                            Win2();
                            Log.Info("Opening Win2");
                            break;
                        // more cases here...
                        case "":
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MessageBoxResult.No:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        }
        obj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for Win2()

```
private void Win2()
{
    var wn = new Win2();
    wn.Show();
    Log.Info("Initiating Win2");
}
```

Finally, here's the close on Win2... Also, the hatchet job for getting around this is in the Window_Closed code. I really don't want to do this...

```
// Saying GoodBye gracefully...
private void Window_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show(
        "Be Sure That All Forms Are Completed Before Closing The Application.\nDo You Want To Close This Program?",
        "Application Close Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) !=
        MessageBoxResult.OK) return;
    Close();

}
private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
    System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
}
```

If I had to wager a guess, I need to do more in the MainWindow.xaml.cs to dispose of the old form and create a new one on double click, but as usual, I'm clueless on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you've shown here, it does look like your Win2 window is being destroyed and recreated properly every time. When wn goes out of scope (in the Win2 method) it will be released. And even if it weren't, you're creating a *new* instance of the window every time (with the new keyword), so in the *worst* case you'd be leaking memory by holding multiple instances of the window:

```
var wn = new Win2();
```

Are you sure you aren't holding onto some global state *outside* of that window, e.g. in your MainWindow or elsewhere, such as some DataTable or query result? That seems to be a more likely culprit. Make sure that all of these are created new within the window and not held by a global instance somewhere else.

Comment: Please bare with me on this... I'm a real newbie stumbling through this line by line. So if my responses seem lame, they probably are.

My MainWindow is only designed to show the user the forms. It really doesnt have much other than that, except a LoadForms() that pulls the form from BizLogic project that uses a get;set for each form name, desc, date, etc.

Comment: My Win2.xaml uses several classes from the DataLogic project. For instance, when I retrieve data, I enter a customer number and press a button. That button runs RetrieveFormData.ReturnFormData() & GetReturnedFormData(). The RetrieveFormData.ReturnFormData() is just an Stored Proc that selects the DB values. The GetReturnedFormData() is local to Win2 and it sets the values from the reader in RetrieveFormData.ReturnFormData() to the text boxes and labels and radio buttons. I think this is the problem child... I need to find a way to dispose of GetReturnedFormData() so it knows its job is done.

Comment: Is anything in Win2.xaml.cs a _static_? Those objects would be preserved between instances of the Window, by definition (they relate to the class, not the instance). What you're looking for are things that aren't getting torn down. I'm not familiar with DataLogic but it's likely there's something in there that is kept alive.

Comment: Noting in Win2.xaml.cs is static. Everything in DataLogic.RetrieveFormData is static (public static string var1). If I dont do this, I get stuck with cannot access non-static field in static context when I try to call RetrieveFormData.ReturnFormData(); in Win2.xaml.cs. 

Example: From Win2.xaml.cs changing  RetrieveFormData  to just public string - 
private void GetReturnedFormData() {
PatNameTxtbx.Text = RetrieveFormData.PatNameRet;
...
This results in cannot access non-static field 'PatNameRet' in static context

Comment: you're a genius... You put me in the perfect spot to fix this. You pushed me in the right direction to the lake and made me fish for it... THANK YOU. 

I made everything public strings in RetrieveFormData class
I went to the retrieve button and removed all the code. 
I made one reference to GetReturnedFormData()
Inside there, I did... 
var rfd = new RetrieveFormData {PatId = SPatIdSearch.Text};
rfd.ReturnFormData();

That allowed me to do this:

Comment: That allowed me to do this:PatNameTxtbx.Text = rfd.PatNameRet; and get rid of the non-static error. Furthermore, it now works correctly when the DB updates the record. No more closing!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of help, I could tell there was some state being held outside your form somewhere. We've all been through something like this at one time or another. Kudos.